# SgmlReader infinite loop on large document?

Tags: sgmlreader

I've got this project to scrape data off of the SEC Edgar site.  Part of the task is to get the meat of the whole filing, and I was just testing some of that today.

I ran into this somewhat large filing (https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/355437/000119312520189547/0001193125-20-189547.txt) that's about 110 meg.

I was breaking up the package to the constituent <DOCUMENT> nodes and processing them differently, based on the FILENAME node value.  For the types that were html/xml based, I just used

```
SgmlReader.ReadInnerXml();
```

to grab the innards, but on this large filing, it appears to go into this infinite loop.  It ran for 15 minutes before I broke in with the debugger, and it was hung on that call.

Has anyone ever run into that before?

I'm using SqmlReader 1.8.16.

I saw a very old comment on a changelog page saying that there was such a bug with improperly terminated html comments but that was listed as fixed a good number of releases ago.

Thanks

Comment: A little update: I tried using SgmlReader.InputStream.ReadLine() to grab the raw innards and then tried to feed it to HtmlAgility Pack.

While SgmlReader.ReadInnerXml() went into an infinite loop on this html, it was memory stable in the looping.

HtmlAgility Pack also went into a loop reading it, but it kept consuming memory until it OOMed.

Comment: I've been playing with this more and it seems that SgmlReader.ReadInnerXml() is just *very slow*.  I let it run to completion (which turned out to be between 16-20 minutes).  It did consume memory, just very very slowly.

Comment: I could use SgmlReader.Skip() and it jumped over the 110 meg in about a second.  I could use SgmlReader.InputStream.ReadLine() and assemble the whole string I expected from SgmlReader.ReadInnerXml() in a couple of seconds.  But ReadInnerXml() took north of 16 minutes.  Don't know why that is.